# Set PDF metadata via Ruby or Command line tool

Tags: ruby

Within my ruby program, I'd like to open an existing PDF file, set the title and author metadata, and save the file.

I've look through the documentation of Prawn and other PDF libraries, but no luck. If there isn't a ruby way to do it, a command line utility (pdftk?) is OK, but preferably available as a Mac and Linux binary.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: pdftk is available for Mac and Linux. If you have that installed, you can call them through ruby using `\`\``, `%x{}`, `open`, or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prawn is the premier PDF library for ruby, but it seems to be a writer only, not a reader.

The simplest command line tool for Linux/Mac to install and use, by far, seems to be exiftools, and this is what I'm using in my scripts.

An example command is:
exiftools -Title="My Title" -Subject="My Subject" -overwrite_original